# Starting with text that has an inset shadow, how do I make a color transition for each letter, as I hover over each letter? Only using CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css, text, colors, transition

Starting with text that has an inset shadow, how do I make a color transition for each letter, as I hover over each letter?  Only using CSS & HTML.

I want to create the effect of a stone tablet's letters lighting up red, similar to fire.  For a creative school project.

Also, if doing individual words, rather than letters is easier, that would be fine too.

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

h1 {
  font: bold 100px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #565656;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  transition: 2s;
}

h1:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<h1>Thou shall code.</h1>
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/desandro/Ew6Zt/ . You will fall in love with it.

Comment: We can't help you with your homework until you at least show us what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry, new to this, I've updated my post with my current code.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to target each individual letter (or word) is to wrap them in `span`s and target the `span`s with the css. In this example I have wrapped each letter in a `span`.

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

h1 {
  font: bold 100px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #565656;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

h1 span {
  transition: 2s;
}
h1 span:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<h1><span>T</span><span>h</span><span>o</span><span>u</span> <span>s</span><span>h</span><span>a</span><span>l</span><span>l</span> <span>c</span><span>o</span><span>d</span><span>e</span>.</h1>
```